# Why does using a function declaration not work for onmessage with web workers?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

The TL;DR is that when the onmessage() handler for a web worker is defined as a function declaration as opposed to a function expression, it doesn't work. (At least in Chrome.) And I can't for the life of me think of why.

I have the following dirt-simple example setup:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Web worker test</title>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="test1" onclick="run('test1.js')">
  <input type="button" value="test2" onclick="run('test2.js')">
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```js
function run(filename) {
  worker = new Worker(filename);
  worker.postMessage("test");
}
```

test1.js

```js
onmessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.data);
}
console.log(self.onmessage);
```

test2.js

```js
function onmessage(msg) {
    console.log(msg.data);
}
console.log(self.onmessage);
```

You can try this yourself at http://mrbean.cryogenia.com/~davedude/webworkertest/ . If you click the test1 button, it logs the following (on Chrome 79.0.3945.117 at least):

```
ƒ (msg) {
  console.log(msg.data);
}
test1.js:2 test
```

This shows that the function is defined as expected, and the handler is working.

In contrast, when you click test2, all you get is this:

```
ƒ onmessage(msg) {
  console.log(msg.data);
}
```

This shows the script *is* working, and the function is defined, it's just not functioning as a handler for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The global object's `onmessage` property is a *setter*. Setters do not get invoked by function declarations; rather, they simply get overwritten, as if `delete <fnName>` was run beforehand. Here's another example:

```html
<script>
Object.defineProperty(window, 'fn', {
  set(newVal) {
    console.log('setter invoked');
  },
  configurable: true
});
</script>
<script>
function fn() {
}

console.log(window.fn);
</script>
```

As you can see, the setter does not get invoked. The state of the `fn` property on `window` after the first `<script>` is nearly the same as the state of the `message` property on `self` in the web worker at the start of the web worker's script:

```js
const workerFn = () => {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(self, 'onmessage'));
};
const workerFnStr = `(${workerFn})();`;
const blob = new Blob([workerFnStr], { type: 'text/javascript' });
const worker = new Worker(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

```html
<div>Look at results in your browser console, not the snippet console</div>

<br><br>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JND8.png">
```

The functionality of setting the function as a listener for the `message` event will only occur inside the setter. But without the setter being invoked, the listener will not be attached.

---

If you're curious, [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation), when a function declaration on the top level exists, and that name already exists on the global object, that name will not be re-created or re-initialized until, at the very end:

> Perform ! `varEnvRec.SetMutableBinding(fn, fo, false)`.

This will throw an error [only if the binding is immutable](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records-setmutablebinding-n-v-s) (eg, if the property is not configurable). But the `onmessage` getter/setter *is* configurable.

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me

```
const work = new Worker(new URL('WebWorker.js', import.meta.url));
work.postMessage({ action: "start_websocket" });
work.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
    console.log("Message received from worker", event.data)
  })
```

Event Listener for Worker Messages: work.addEventListener('message', ...) listens for messages sent from the web worker. When a message is received, the provided callback function is executed. In this case, it logs the received data to the console.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35685839)